# openapi-generator-maven-plugin doesnt generate response headers for library - webclient

Tags: java

I have model in **open-api v.3** spec. I use **openapi-generator-maven-plugin** to generate java client for library **webclient** (spring 5 - webflux). I want to send back to client file and http headers. Generated code doesn't have method to get response headers.

Generated code for client doesn't contains code which provide access to response headers. For example if I use library resttemplate there is **method  public MultiValueMap getResponseHeaders()** . Is there a way how to get response headers with library -webclient ?

template for resttemplate library contains this: 
private MultiValueMap responseHeaders;
link: [github](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/resttemplate/ApiClient.mustache)

code for webclient is here: [github](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/webclient/ApiClient.mustache)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? :)

Comment: honestly I don't remember it is 18months ago :). Most probably we used some kind of workaround.

Comment: @AndersS I'm stuck at the same point. Did you find a solution? I've just filed a bug in the project 

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9418

Comment: Michal Šiplák in the meantime were you able to remember how you got over that problem? It would be very helpful.. :)

Comment: I ended up downloading the mustache templates for the generator and changing them to return the whole response, not just the resulting body. Not pretty, but it works. Specifically api.mustache and ApiClient.mustache .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenAPI generator was extended since 5.2 and now the webclient library has two methods for each endpoint one with suffix `WithHttpInfo` and with a return type `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>` . See [PR #9327](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/9327). So if you have for example an endpoint `getUser` it generates:

```java
Mono<UserDTO> getUser();

Mono<ResponseEntity<UserDTO>> getUserWithHttpInfo();
```

Then you can call a method with `WithHttpInfo` which returns `ResponseEntity` and call `ResponseEntity#getHeaders`

```java
getUserWithHttpInfo().getHeaders()
```